# How to reference jQuery object inside of it's own method call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm trying to do this:

```
$('.summary').css('top',$(this).outerHeight());
```

Where I reference 'this' I would like to reference the instance of $('.summary') that jquery is currently talking to, since there are multiple, but the scope considers 'this' the page in this instance.

What's the easiest way to reference each element in this case?

I looked through the search for the answer for this, but don't quite know the right phrasing. If this has been answered let me know and I can close as a duplicate.

Thanks!

Comment: Guess you're feeling pretty resistent to the idea of declaring a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a function directly to `.css()`.

```
$('.summary').css('top',function() {
    return $(this).outerHeight();
});
```

It will iterate the elements, and the return values will be the new values for `'top'`.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), I think.

```
$('.summary').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('top', $this.outerHeight());
});
```

**EDIT:** Less requerying. Also, I like `am not i am`'s answer more. It's slightly more elegant.

Comment: You're requerying for what you already have. You should be storing a reference to the first query and using that later. If you were to do that, though, you'd then have a needlessly long version of Lawson Kurtz's answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. FWIW, it works to omit the units on the top attribute but I'm sure you're way is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should define it as a variable first, then you can reference it in the method:

```
var summary = $('.summary');
summary.css('top',summary.outerHeight());
```

Comment: As this is a class and could stand for multiple elements this would be unreliable.